# Problems when placing environment variables in the prism project

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a graphql project using the prism but when executing the command `npx prisma deploy -e ../config/dev.env` I get the following error:

```
post-deploy:
[
  "[WARNING] in D:\\Projetos\\graphql3\\graphql-prisma\\prisma\\prisma.yml: A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT' could not be found."
]
ListrError: Something went wrong
    at D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\listr\index.js:102:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async executeCodegen (D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\index.cjs.js:812:5)
    at async Object.generate (D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\index.cjs.js:1102:25)
    at async Object.handler (D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-cli\codegen\index.cjs.js:23:13) {
  errors: [
    Error: No cluster set. Please set the "cluster" property in your prisma.yml
        at PrismaLoader.load (D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-tools\prisma-loader\index.cjs.js:1296:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
        at async loadFile (D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-tools\load\index.cjs.js:48:24)
        at async D:\Projetos\graphql3\graphql-prisma\node_modules\@graphql-tools\load\index.cjs.js:425:24 {
      source: './src/generated/prisma.graphql',
      context: [Object: null prototype] {}
    }
  ],
  context: [Object: null prototype] {}
}
```

The project's folder architecture is in this format

[image]

my `prisma.yml`

```yml
endpoint: ${env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT}
datamodel: datamodel.graphql
secret: thisisasecret
hooks:
  post-deploy:
    - graphql codegen --project database # instead of graphql get-schema
    # - prisma generate**strong text**
```

`config\dev.env` has content

```
PRISMA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4466
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "graphql-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "get-schema": "graphql codegen --project database"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "graphql-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "prisma-binding": "^2.3.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-cli/codegen": "^1.17.8",
    "@graphql-codegen/schema-ast": "^1.17.8",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

I didn't find anything related and even trying to put the .env in the root where the prisma.yml file is, with the default name .env doesn't work